# How to add server dynamically in HA proxy backend?

Tags: tcp, load-balancing, haproxy

I am using HA proxy version 1.6.6 for load balancing rabbitmq server, and  it works fine but i want to add server dynamically in ha proxy backend in ubuntu using script. can anyone please tell me how can i done it?

Answer (score 12):

HAProxy OSS v1.8 does not include `add/remove` commands in Runtime API, but you can achieve similar functionality by using  `ready/disabled` state commands.

- Add server(s) config in haproxy.cfg in `disabled` state: `server-template websrv 1-100 192.168.122.1:8080 check disabled` //*This adds 100 servers (websrv1...websrv100) in disabled state*
- Enable server (similar to `add` feature): `set server be_template/websrv1 state ready`
- Disable server (similar to `remove` feature): `set server be_template/websrv1 state maint`

Address and port can be changed using Runtime API as usual: `set server be_template/websrv1 addr 192.168.50.112 port 8000`

Reference(s):

1. https://www.haproxy.com/blog/dynamic-configuration-haproxy-runtime-api/
2. https://www.haproxy.com/blog/dynamic-scaling-for-microservices-with-runtime-api/

Comment: This does not work in haproxy 1.8: "Update for the current server address family is only supported through configuration file"

Comment: Changing server addresses is working in HA-Proxy version 2.0.7 2019/09/27

Comment: Unknown command: 'server-template', but maybe one of the following ones is a better match -- haproxy 2.8

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know haproxy api ( stats socket ) does not support dynamic adding/removing servers to backend. 
One of the solution to use consul, the cost - reload service after some change.
https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/haproxy-with-consul.html

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not this kind of features with HAProxy Open Source.

If you use their ALOHA Load Balancer, there is an API to do this actions here :

https://www.haproxy.com/resources/documentation/